# Cartesian Equations Intersecting

Tags: vector-spaces

One line $L_1$ has a cartesian equation $x+1=\frac{y}{3}=-z.$
Another line $L_2$ has a cartesian equation $2x+1=2y+1=z+a$, where $a$ is not known.
$L_1$ and $L_2$ intersect in a point, so find the value of $a$.

Comment: Answered down below. Make sure to vote up and accept the answer if it fits you and ask me whatever you need if you did not understand something :)

Answer (score 1):

We have :

$ L_1 : x+1 = \frac {y}{3} = -z $ and $ L_2 : 2x+1=2y+1=z+a$

Solve for :

$ x = \frac {y}{3} - 1 $ and then $ 2y + 1 = \frac{2y}{3} - 1 \Leftrightarrow y = \frac {-6}{4} $

Then $ y = -3z $. You get : $ - 6z + 1 = z + a \Leftrightarrow a = -7z + 1 $

But : $ z = - \frac {y}{3} \Leftrightarrow z = \frac {1}{2} $ Because : $ y = \frac {-6}{4} $.

Finally : $ a = -  \frac {7}{2} + 1 $

The way you solve it is by equating the "Xs" and "Ys" and "Zs" .

Answer (score 1):

HINT

I would say, solve the system of linear equations:

$x+1=y/3,y/3=-z, \quad 2x+1=2y+1, 2y+1=z+a$

($\Rightarrow a=-5/2, \quad x = -3/2, \quad y=-3/2,\quad z = 1/2$)